# Codifferential of a wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Is there a simple formula for the action of the codifferential on a wedge product of forms

$d^\dagger (a \wedge b) = *d*(a \wedge b)$?

I was hoping for something like

$d^\dagger (a \wedge b) = (d^\dagger a) \wedge b + (-1)^p a \wedge (d^\dagger b)$

but that doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: Just want to make sure: does $*$ mean Hodge star operator?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by $*$.  There's a bit more information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual#The_codifferential